# Incrementing values more than once on mysql on a single UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I've been looking for an answer to my problem but to no avail.
The problem is as follows, when I try to update a value more than once on a single UPDATE statement in SQL it will always update once. Is as if the UPDATE statement is working over a copy of my table and always overwriting the value on the original table, hence the resulting table only has the value incremented by 1 and not by the number of times the value was set with value=value+1.

Here's an example:

```
UPDATE Home, Person
SET Home.NumberOfChilds=Home.NumberOfChilds+1
WHERE Home.State= Person.State
AND Home.ZoneCode = Person.ZoneCode 
AND Home.Address = Person.Address
AND Person.IsChild = true;
```

In this case, if a home has 3 childs the resulting amount of children would be 1 on that home, when I need it to be 3. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's just an example because the JOIN is much longer and my tables and attributes are not in English. State, ZoneCode and Adress would be the PK of Home, and State, ZoneCode, Adress and NumberOfPerson would be the PK of Person, and the first three of those would be a FK referencing Home. NumberOfChilds is a Decimal(4,0). Hope it helps, thanks for your interest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly do the count in a subselect joined against your main table:-

```
UPDATE Home
INNER JOIN (SELECT State, ZoneCode, Address, COUNT(*) AS PersonCount FROM Person WHERE IsChild = true GROUP BY  State, ZoneCode, Address) Sub1
ON Home.State= Sub1.State
AND Home.ZoneCode = Sub1.ZoneCode 
AND Home.Address = Sub1.Address
SET Home.NumberOfChilds = Home.NumberOfChilds + Sub1.PersonCount
```

Answer (score 0):

This works with Sql Server 2008R2, I don't have access to to a mysql system to test at the moment.

```
UPDATE H
SET H.NumberOfChilds = ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Person AS P
    WHERE H.State = P.State
    AND H.ZoneCode = P.ZoneCode
    AND H.Address = P.Address
    AND P.IsChild = 1 )                       
FROM Home AS H
```

I don't think you will be able to get multiple increments of 1 from a single statement, you will need to use some form of count instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I forgot to mention that my tables have millions of rows and that solution takes too much time to complete, but I'm sure it would work

Comment: My answer will probably exhibit the same weakness then, though indexes might help as might a surrogate key e.g Person.HomeId. Other than that, you might have to look at building the output via a trigger or stored proc

Comment: This relies on a correlated subselect which is likely to perform badly. Both my solution and the very similar one by @TonyHopkinson shouldn't suffer in this way.

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
Update h
Set h.NumberOfChilds = c.ChildCount
From Home h
inner join (Select ZoneCode, Address, Count(*) as ChildCount 
            From Person Where IsChild = true Group By ZoneCode,Address) c
On c.ZoneCode = h.ZoneCode and c.Address = h.Address
```

maybe.

All you are doing is incrementing child count for all homes with at lest one matching child each time you run the query.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works that way like I told Kickstart.